# Swift AnyObject protocol conformance issue

Tags: swift, class, swift-protocols

is anyone able to tell me why this does not work in Swift 3?
I have a protocol which conforms to AnyObject like this:

```
protocol EventListenerProtocol: AnyObject {
    func doSomething()
}
```

then I have an emitter protocol with default implementation like this:

```
protocol EventEmitterProtocol {
    associatedtype ListenerType

    var listeners: [ListenerType] { get set }

    func addEventListener(_ listener: ListenerType)
    func removeEventListener(_ listener: ListenerType)
}

extension EventEmitterProtocol where ListenerType: AnyObject {

  ... funcs implemented ...

}
```

removeEventListener requires ListenerType to be AnyObject to be able to use identity operator.

After all that, I'm trying to use this in my class:

```
class myClass: EventEmitterProtocol {

    var listeners: [EventListenerProtocol] = []

}
```

and it says my class does not conform to EventEmitterProtocol. When I change EventListenerProtocol to AnyObject as the array type, it does compile. EventListenerProtocol conforms to AnyObject, so why the error pops up? I'd be really grateful for any help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself)

Comment: I think this is a different case, because my error message says that myClass does not conform to EventEmitterProtocol.

Comment: It's the same problem, as `EventListenerProtocol` is not a type that conforms to `AnyObject` – thus you don't get the `extension EventEmitterProtocol where ListenerType: AnyObject` with the default implementations of your methods, meaning your class doesn't conform to `EventEmitterProtocol`, as it doesn't have an implementation for those method requirements.

Comment: I still have no idea how to solve my problem tho. Sorry, this is still a bit complicated for me, as I'm rather new to Swift. I want to be able to add and remove listeners to myClass using addEventListener and removeEventListener funcs, but this would work from different places, so listener must be a protocol, I also wanted to move the default implementation to the Emitter protocol. Do I have to move it back to the main class, or is there some way to get through it? I read the answers on the link you gave, but it didn't help me much to solve the problem.

Comment: You'll likely have to build [a type eraser](http://robnapier.net/erasure) (as the linked Q&A suggests) in order to wrap a `EventListenerProtocol` conforming instance in a concrete type, and then have an array of that concrete type for your `listeners`.